# ClassNotFoundException while calling a class in main application from java agent extension

Tags: classloader, classnotfoundexception, javaagents

I am running a spring boot application, which has a dependency in pom.xml (i.e., client-library)
A java agent extension is running parallelly with spring boot application. I am trying to call a class in client-library class from a class in java agent extension, which gives class not found exception.

NOTE: If I run same thing in eclipse, it will run properly. I checked in eclipse run configuration, it sets all jar files in class path and invokes the spring boot main class along with extension.
I use Class.forName(pachage_name) to call the client library from java agent extension.

**It do not work when deployed through command line, can anyone suggest how to fix class not found exception.**

copied boot_inf/lib and boot_inf/classes from generated jar and pasted in a folder and set in classpath and invoked main class. App runs properly. **But I want to run it as a java -jar only hence want to fix class not found exception.**

java -javaagent:"opentelemetry-javaagent-1.15.0.jar" -Dotel.resource.attributes=***** -Dotel.service.name=**** -Dotel.traces.exporter=**** -Dotel.metrics.exporter=**** -Dotel.javaagent.enabled=true -Dcontrast.agent.java.standalone_app_name=***** -Dotel.javaagent.extensions="otel-agent-ext-java-1.2.49-m3.jar" -classpath "C:\classes;C:\lib*" com.xyz.otelc.MainClass

I have to dpeloy this on cloudfoundry and only thing i can do is cf push and no option to set class paths.